# Creating a model using JSON and HTTP POST when the model has a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class TaskRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime RequestedDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway I could set up a `HttpPost` method that can create a model to be inserted into a database in `ASP.NET`?

My current Task post method:

```
// POST /api/taskrequests
[HttpPost]
public TaskRequest CreateTaskRequest(TaskRequest taskRequest)
{           
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

     _context.TaskRequests.Add(taskRequest);
     _context.SaveChanges();
     return taskRequest;
}
```

I currently using `HttpGet` get the employee and `stringify` the whole TaskRequest as a JSON string

```
var task = new Object();
task.Title = taskTitle;
task.Body = taskBody;
task.RequestedDateTime = new Date(taskDate + " " + taskTime);
task.Employee = JSON.stringify(employee);
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(task);
```

Then send that to my API, but employee is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should call JSON.stringify only once:

```
var task = new Object();
task.Title = taskTitle;
task.Body = taskBody;
task.RequestedDateTime = new Date(taskDate + " " + taskTime);
var employee = new Object();
//add employee properties here
task.Employee = employee;
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(task);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, You should write your custom model binder, in ASP.net mvc you cant bind complex model except simple model, you should implement IModelBinder interface and registre it

try to look those linkes

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc/